# Child categories of sub category not listed

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a 3-stage category list.

1. Main Category
2. Sub Category
3. Child Category

Main category and subcategory are working but can not display child category. Additionally, the  "choose " option does not appear in the subcategories If the relevant category is selected.

Where am I making a mistake?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $cat = $('select[name=categoMain]'),
    $items = $('select[name=categoSubMain]');
  $items2 = $('select[name=categoChildMain]');

  $cat.change(function() {
    var $this = $(this).find(':selected'),
      rel = $this.attr('rel'),
      $set = $items.find('option.' + rel);
    if ($set.size() < 0) {
      $items.hide();
      return;
    }
    $items.show().find('option').hide();
    $set.show().first().prop('selected', true);
    /* Child category */
    $items.change(function() {
      var $this = $(this).find(':selected'),
        rel = $this.attr('rel'),
        $set = $items2.find('option.' + rel);
      if ($set.size() < 0) {
        $items2.hide();
        return;
      }
      $items2.show().find('option').hide();
      $set.show().first().prop('selected', true);
    });
    /* */
  });
});
```

```css
.cate {
  display: none;
}

.cate2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="categoMain">
  <option value="0" class="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1" rel="accessories">Cellphones</option>
  <option value="2" rel="sports">Sports</option>
  <option value="2" rel="cars">Cars</option>
</select>
<select name="categoSubMain" class="cate">
  <option value="0" class="">Choose</option>
  <option value="3" class="accessories">Smartphone</option>
  <option value="8" class="accessories">Charger</option>
  <option value="1" class="sports">Basketball</option>
  <option value="4" class="cars">Tesla</option>
</select>
<select name="categoChildMain" class="cate2">
  <option value="0" class="">Choose</option>
  <option value="3" class="accessories">Smartphone</option>
  <option value="1" class="sports">Basketball</option>
</select>
```

[**JSFiddle Version**](http://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/4g0w8mu6/1/)

Comment: your subcategories don't seem to have attr rel, although you are doing this `rel = $this.attr('rel'),`

Comment: @seethrough How should I make a change?

Comment: I don't get your HTML : why are the value this way? Is it from a database? And why for the first to you have 2 times the value = 2? Are those value related or not at all?

Comment: @MickaelLeger This datas is sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed your code a bit. It does what you wanted but now you are facing another problem - what if you have one option? Give me time, i will come up with something

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedData = {}
  $('select[name="categoMain"], select[name="categoSubMain"],select[name="categoChildMain"]').change(function () {
     var $this = $(this).find(':selected');
        selectedData[$(this).attr('name')]=$this.val()
     var rel = $this.data('rel');
        $(this).next('select').show()
          .find('option').hide()
          .end().find('option[data-rel="' + rel+'"]').show()
          .first().prop('selected', true);
        $(this).next('select').next('select').hide()
        console.log(selectedData);
  });
});
```

```css
.cate {
    display: none;
}
.cate2 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="categoMain">
    <option value="0" data-rel="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1" data-rel="accessories">Cellphones</option>
    <option value="2" data-rel="sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="2" data-rel="cars">Cars</option>
</select>
<select name="categoSubMain" class="cate">
    <option value="0" data-rel="">Choose</option>
    <option value="3" data-rel="accessories">Smartphone</option>
    <option value="8" data-rel="accessories">Charger</option>
    <option value="1" data-rel="sports">Basketball</option>
    <option value="4" data-rel="cars">Tesla</option>
</select>
<select name="categoChildMain" class="cate2">
    <option value="0" data-rel="">Choose</option>
    <option value="3" data-rel="accessories">Smartphone</option>
    <option value="1" data-rel="sports">Basketball</option>
</select>
```

Comment: For example; I first selected the "Cellphones > Changer"; After If I choose "Cars". The third box _(Smartphone)_ still looks. Can you hide third box? I hope I can tell you the right way.

Comment: Have a look, I made some changes

Comment: This new coding is very short! Nice but I don't think you can work on the website because it's dont have ID of DIV. I'll try it now

Comment: what ID and what div? i didn't touch any ids. and if the question is right don't hesitate to chose it, please

Comment: I wanted to talk about them: `categoMain`, `categoSubMain` or `categoChildMain`. Because the site did not work in the interface

Comment: what exact thing that you need about them?

Comment: It does not work because there are many select box on the page. But no problem, I will use the previous your code. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: @Sahipsiz i have made some changes in answer to tackle only selectors you mentioned

Comment: Do you know? 
You are great! Thanks